# bug in the reputation league - some sites not selected in the drop down when viewing their rankings

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

For example on:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/34/week/webapps/2018-09-23?sort=reputationchange

In the drop-down at the top of the page:

[image]

If you switch between the sites, many of the times it reverts back to the top item.

Not fully tested but it seems to work for full domain sites, but the subdomain sites it won't find itself in the list and will default to StackOverflow (first result).

This means you cannot actually then navigate to StackOverflow stats.

Repro:

1. visit https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/week/math
2. observe StackOverflow is selected in the list not Mathematics
3. select SuperUser
4. observe it loads and selects itself correctly in that drop down
5. select Blender
6. observe it selects StackOverflow

Comment: Seems a little more complex than just reverts to the top item. Example: select English Language & Usage, get Physical Fitness.